# PHP Twitter API - How to pull in multiple users tweets?

Tags: php, twitter

How would I go about pulling in tweets from multiple twitter users with PHP and displaying them as part of one combined list on my page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the search API and boolean OR operator. For example here is the URL for CNN Breaking News and NPR All Things Considered:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from%3acnnbrk+OR+from%3anpratc

The query is URLEncoded so use Fiddler Tools -> Text Encode/Decode or your favorite tool to see that the correct format in plain text is:

`q=from:cnnbrk+OR+from:npratc`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately using the search doesn't guarantee that all tweets are included, since it's not sure that all tweets are indexed.

Comment: Another note is this method is now dead and wont work due to end of Twitter 1.0 API

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a list of the accounts you are interested in and place a list widget on your page. No PHP needed.

http://help.twitter.com/entries/76460-how-to-use-twitter-lists

http://twitter.com/goodies/widget_list

Comment: This is great - but I'd prefer an answer to the question.

Comment: I did answer the question. I provided an alternative method of accomplishing the desired goal of presenting tweets from multiple Twitter users on a webpage.