# Combine multiple twitter feeds into one list with PHP?

Tags: php, twitter

How would I go about combining multiple users twitter feeds into one list and display them on my page?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692434/php-twitter-api-how-to-pull-in-multiple-users-tweets

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to go in, I'd say, three steps :

- Get the feed of each one of the users

  - Those are available as RSS feeds ; for example : http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/17907318.rss
  - This means you can download it with [**`curl`**](https://www.php.net/curl), or download+read it with [**`simplexml_load_file`**](https://www.php.net/simplexml_load_file).
- When you have downloaded the feed for each user, and parsed it, you have several arrays of feeds.

  - You'll have to merge those into a single array, containing all the feeds of all users ; see [**`array_merge`**](http://fr.php.net/array_merge)
  - And, then, probably sort that array by date ; see [**`usort`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
- And, finally, you'll have to display the resulting array, the way you want it.

As a sidenote : downloading several RSS feeds each time you want to display your resulting page is not a good idea : it will slow your site down a lot -- which means you need to put some caching mecanism in place :

- either cache the tweets data ; for example, using a MySQL database
- or cache the whole resulting portion of HTML code

Comment: +1 for caching.  From memory, Twitter may also block your site/application if you retrieve the user feeds more than X number of times an hour (I think!)