# Twitter API - I want to grab all the tweets by a certain user (actually, a whole bunch of users) (php)

Tags: php, api, twitter

I have a list of various twitter accounts (usernames). I want to grab a feed of their statuses (public).

How can i do that with their api?

i can only see how to do it if i were to:

1. make a new twitter account (@myaccount)
2. follow all the twitter accounts i want to grab their statuses from
3. use oAuth to authorise @myaccount
4. get all the statuses from that accounts timeline and process that

how can i do this the proper way?

Comment: To be honest, the way you have laid out __is__ the proper way IMO. It is also by far the easiest as you can do everything you need via the /statuses/home_timeline feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a twitter list https://support.twitter.com/entries/76460-how-to-use-twitter-lists and output via a widget https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_list.

this answer was from here but some of the links are broken [Combine multiple twitter feeds into one list with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697092/combine-multiple-twitter-feeds-into-one-list-with-php).

Or you could do the way you suggested using this php class http://code.google.com/p/twitter-php/ and using the Twitter::ME_AND_FRIENDS option