# Twitter - Multiple User's Posts?

Tags: c#, xml, http, windows-phone-7, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Twitter API - How to pull in multiple users tweets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692434/php-twitter-api-how-to-pull-in-multiple-users-tweets)

Is there a way to use some simple http request, like the following:

`http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=badreligion`

to get multiple user's timelines in a single request? Something like (pseudocode):

`http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name[]=badreligion,testa,another`

I've looked through their api a bit, but with little luck.

**EDIT:** If they could be merged and sorted by time, that'd be awesome. As it is now, I use a loop to iterate over the feeds I want, then combine them, sort the structure, etc, and it is just so messy.

Comment: I was searching for the same thing and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5119632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this current time, I don't believe that twitter supplies an API function that allows you to get multiple user time lines in a single request.

If you are concerned about the amount of time it takes to loop through the users, you could request the time lines asynchronously so that you can be getting several user's timelines at the same time.  You can implement a background thread for each request or use [HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) function.

Comment: I am already doing the loads with HttpWebRequest, but I was hoping to offload some of the processing from the user's phone. I'll see if anyone else has a better idea, and if not I'll accept your answer as a sad truth! :)

Comment: Well, since you are wanting to off load the work from the phone and Twitter is not offering it in the form of an API, the best solution would be for you or someone else to implement a middle tier server that will do the work and then hand your phone client the results.

Comment: I suppose I could do that with my server, not a bad idea!

Comment: Or you could create a Twitter user that follows multiple people, and retrieve that users timeline.