# How to retrieve multiple user statuses with the twitter API

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Let's say I have a list of 5 twitter handles and I want to select the top 15 tweets from each of them. AND only do it in one query returned as jsonp. (This will help to overcome the 150 "GET" rate limit and work nicer with backbone)

Currently I am using the search API in this way: https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=codinghorror&count=15

Any way I could throw an extra screen name in there?

Comment: Maybe using search API is your best bet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PHP question might help you:

[PHP Twitter API - How to pull in multiple users tweets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692434/php-twitter-api-how-to-pull-in-multiple-users-tweets)

Unfortunately the twitter API isn't designed to give you that many results. With the search URL from the question above the limit is 15, so if one of the users has 15 tweets more recently than the others you are searching for than the other users tweets will be 'buried'.

So if you query this:
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from%3acnnbrk+OR+from%3anpratc

It appears at the time of me writing this that @ccnbrk tweets more than @npratc and @npratc only shows once in the result.

APIs are generally designed to return small datasets to keep response time up and in turn encourages users to get a higher rate plan.